# ImageMagick apply watermark multiple times

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, imagemagick-convert

Currently, with ImageMagick I apply `watermark.png` on top of `picture.jpg` in the center using:

`convert -size 700x1300 -composite picture.jpg watermark.png -gravity center -geometry 700x1300 output.jpg`

This nicely overlays my watermark in the middle of the image. However, I want to achieve this effect in the top-left, center, and bottom-right. I've tried combining multiple `-composite`s with no result. I would like to avoid calling 3 different commands to avoid the extra overhead it introduces, but I'm starting to believe it isn't possible without doing so.

What can I do to achieve the three watermark positions in one command, `NorthWest`, `Center` and `SouthEast`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, there is a -gravity setting that allows you to put the watermark in various locations specified by the compass directions. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity. However, your syntax is not proper and may fail for use with IM 7. The proper syntax is to read the input image first. So your command should be

```
convert background watermark -gravity center -compose over -composite output
```

Change center to one of the other gravity settings such as northwest or southeast

Also your -size does nothing in your command. If you want to use -size WxH xc:somecolor, then you would use that in place of the background.

If you want to resize, then do not use -geometry. That is typically used for offsetting the gravity placement. Use -resize WxH if you want to resize the result.

See 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert

I would modify GeeMack's answer just slightly so it reads a bit more symmetric:

```
convert watermark.png -write mpr:watermark +delete \
input.png \
mpr:watermark -gravity center -compose over -composite \
mpr:watermark -gravity northwest -compose over -composite \
mpr:watermark -gravity southeast -compose over -composite \
output.png
```

EDITED: to followup with OP question. If you need to resize the watermark, then do

```
convert watermark.png -resize 700x1300 -write mpr:watermark +delete \
input.png \
mpr:watermark -gravity center -compose over -composite \
mpr:watermark -gravity northwest -compose over -composite \
mpr:watermark -gravity southeast -compose over -composite \
output.png
```

Comment: This seems to do what I want to do, but I have to resize the watermark before using it (which I think either -size or -geometry does in the OP). Can I put that in the convert call?

Comment: Nevermind, managed to do it through `-resize`. Thanks - accepted as it addressed my question the best.

Comment: Notice in my example how you read in the watermark image first? Put the "-resize WxH" right after reading it in and before writing it to the mpr: register. The main image gets read in after that so it's unaffected by the resize.

Answer (score 2):

Hold the watermark image in a memory register with "-write mpr:watermark", then recall it into your command for the second and third composite. Here's a simple example of how that works...

```
convert watermark.png -write mpr:watermark input.png +swap \
  -gravity center -composite mpr:watermark -gravity northwest -composite \
  mpr:watermark -gravity southeast -composite output.png
```

Set the geometry before each composite if necessary to give the mark some padding from the corners.